# how $τ^2 = (1, 3, 5, 7)(2, 4, 6, 8)$ come $?$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find the cycle structure of all the powers of $(1, 2, . . . , 8).$

my attempts : i was googling and found the answer but I didn't understand the answer[image]

as  I'm not getting how $τ^2 = (1, 3, 5, 7)(2, 4, 6, 8)$ comes $?$

Comment: What else should $\tau^2$ be? $\tau$ maps $1$ to $2$ and $2$ to $3$, so $\tau^2$ maps $1$ to $3$ etcetera.

Comment: Why don't you try to break $τ^2$ explicitly and match it with $τ•τ ?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that $\tau$ sends $1$ to $2$. Applying $\tau$ again sends $2$ to $3$, so by definition of $^2$, we get that $\tau^2$ sends $1$ to $3$. Thus we start with writing down $\tau^2 = (1, 3$.

Now, $\tau$ sends $3$ to $4$ and $4$ to $5$, so $\tau^2$ sends $3$ to $5$. This gives $\tau^2 = (1, 3, 5$. Continuing this way we get $\tau^2 = (1, 3, 5, 7)$, because $\tau^2(7) = 1$, so we have a full cycle there. However, we're not done yet because we have to see what $\tau^2$ does to the other numbers that $\tau$ touches, namely the even numbers.

So, continuing in the same way, we get $\tau^2(1, 3, 5, 7)(2,4$, then $\tau^2 = (1, 3, 5, 7)(2, 4, 6$, then $\tau^2 = (1, 3, 5, 7)(2, 4, 6, 8)$ and this time we *are* done.

Comment: thanks u @Arthur